# How to load Google Places API in a .js file and not within a <script> element?

Tags: javascript, html, api, google-places-api, api-key

I'm looking at the [Google Places API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places), and they state that I must load the API like this:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>`

Is there any way to load this API through a Javascript file, rather than exposing my API key in an HTML document?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you can do you have to put your API key inside your script tag however if someone wants to use your API key in another domain they will get error.
For more information take look at [API Key Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices)

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to add the script tag to the DOM via javascript, but what would this accomplish? The js is still going to be loaded by the client and you can read a js file just as easily as the html.

Comment: The API key not being committed into git would be accomplished.

Comment: Would you not also be committing the js file?

Comment: Yep. Via the method described here: https://gist.github.com/derzorngottes/3b57edc1f996dddcab25